# Can't fill in the data file

Tags: python, django, file, csv

I work in django. I need to fill in the text file data from the database. The very process of searching for data in the database and change their work, and if I use print to debug, the variables are not empty. They contain data from the database.

```
# encoding: utf-8
# !/usr/bin/python

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import os
from core.db import KeyStore, Fingerprints
import csv
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = u"Переименование файлов кейсторов и обновление данных о них в БД."

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        success_csv = 'success_log.csv'
        error_csv = 'error_log.csv'
        [OUTPUT IN FILE]
        with open(success_csv, 'w') as f:
            f.write('Id;Alias;Old keystore;New keystore;\n')
        [OUTPUT IN FILE]
        with open(error_csv, 'w') as f:
            f.write('Keystore;\n')

        path = '/home/anton/PycharmProjects/apps-ittop-mobi/src/media/keystores'
        list_of_files = os.listdir(path)
        count_of_files = len(list_of_files)
        os.chdir(path)
        for i in range(0, count_of_files):
            old_keystore = 'keystores/%s' % list_of_files[i].encode('utf-8')
            try:
                keystore = KeyStore.objects.get(keystore=old_keystore)
            except(ValueError, KeyStore.DoesNotExist):
                keystore = None
                [NOT OUTPUT IN FILE]
                with open(error_csv, 'a') as f:
                    f.write('%s\n' % old_keystore)
            else:
                try:
                    fingerprints = Fingerprints.objects.get(keystore_id=keystore.pk)
                except(ValueError, Fingerprints.DoesNotExist):
                    fingerprints = None
                else:
                    new_keystore = '%s__%s__.keystore' % (keystore.alias, keystore.keypass)
                    keystore.keystore = 'keystores/%s' % new_keystore
                    keystore.save()
                    fingerprints.save()
                    [NOT OUTPUT IN FILE]
                    with open(success_csv, 'a') as f:
                        f.write('%s;%s;%s;%s;\n' % (keystore.pk, keystore.alias, old_keystore, keystore.keystore))

                    os.rename(os.path.join(path, list_of_files[i]), os.path.join(path, new_keystore))
```

Even if I replace:

```
[NOT OUTPUT IN FILE]
with open(error_csv, 'a') as f:
    f.write('%s\n' % old_keystore)
```

On

```
[NOT OUTPUT IN FILE]
with open(error_csv, 'a') as f:
       f.write('TESTtestTEST\n')
```

In the file nothing is written. Although these sections of code work:

```
[OUTPUT IN FILE]
with open(success_csv, 'w') as f:
       f.write('Id;Alias;Old keystore;New keystore;\n')
[OUTPUT IN FILE]
       with open(error_csv, 'w') as f:
            f.write('Keystore;\n')
```

What are the reasons why the file is not populated with data?

Comment: First of all, are those `[NOT OUTPUT IN FILE]` actually in the file? They should give syntax errors I believe. If they are just comments, use `#` to denote them as comments. Next, could you please confirm that code in `else` blocks are executed (e.g. by debug-printing. Also, it might make sense to flatten the try-expect-else structures, and open file handlers on top and keep them open until you're done - not closing and reopening them in a loop.

Comment: @J0HN '[NOT OUTPUT IN FILE]' These notes I made specially for you in the code are not. To make it easier to understand where the data is output to a file, and where not. At the expense else I do not understand, if everything succeeds, we go to the Else.

Comment: `else` clause is hit only if *no* exceptions is raised. In case there's any exception except`ValueError` or `DoesNotExist` it wouldn't execute neither except nor else clause. So, what I was suggesting is to actually check if there are any exceptions raised, by actually printing something to console/log inside those else clauses.